# Persisting Properties in Models in ASP.NET MVC (with Binder?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given the following code:

### Models

```
class Log
{
   ...
   Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
   string Message { get; set; }
}
class Ticket
{
   ...
   Importance Importance { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

### View

```
<%@ Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.Log>" %>
...
<%= Html.DisplayFor(l => l.Ticket.Name) %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(l => l.Message) %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(l => l.Ticket.Importance) %>
...
```

### Controller Actions

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    Ticket t = _tickets.Get(id);
    return View(new Log { Ticket = t });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Log l)
{
   // My problem is here:
    l.Ticket.Name; // This is null
    l.Ticket.Importance; // while this one is still set
}
```

Is there any way to persist the `Ticket` in the `Log` that is passed?

Comment: You could probably just store the ticket name in a hidden field, but more reasonably you might want to consider simply accepting the way http works rather than fighting it,.

Comment: I doubt this is an HTTP issue.

Comment: It is.. because you aren't sending a Ticket back in the form.. you are sending the importance property and the message property of the log.. it is factually that what you send to the view ISN'T what is sent BACK in the postback.. it is a subset (purposely so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name will be output for display as plain text, meaning that there wont be a variable passed back to your page as part of your post as it isnt part of a form. Workarounds are to put it in a hidden field or lookup your model as part of your Update method then call UpdateModel on the retrieved item.

Comment: I tested without the  `<%= Html.DisplayFor(log => log.Ticket) %>` and it is still `null`.

Comment: You need to add hidden field, not to remove label. Try Html.Hidden(l => l.Ticket.Name) (syntax depend on MVC v2) or smth like <input type="hidden" name="Ticket.Hidden" value="<%= Model.Ticket.Name %>" />.